# Wordpress infinite previous and next with post data

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination, navigation

I am trying to create infinite previous/next buttons for a custom post type. It works perfectly until you reach the last post.

As you can see in my code I check if there is a previous post, if not the else will be executed. Inside this loop I expect to get the first post if I'm currently on the last post of the custom post type, and the other way around.

Instead of showing the first post in this situation, I see data of the current post.

```
$first = new WP_Query('post_type=success-stories&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
```

I think this code is not correct to get the first post. I honestly thought DESC and ASC would determine the first and last post.

```
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(); ?>
<?php if($prevPost) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'success-stories',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'include'           => $prevPost->ID
    );
    $prevPost = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($prevPost as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <div class="hide-medium blogpost-link">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                <?php $thumbnail = get_field('sv_thumbnail_image'); ?>
                <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>)"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <?php
                                $client_image = get_field('blog_client_logo');
                                if( ! empty($client_image) ):
                                    echo '<img src="' . $client_image['url'] . '" alt="">';
                                endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vertical-centered text-center text">
                            <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                            <a class="btn inline-block solid-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lees verder</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="show-medium small-6 prev previous-link">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&larr; Vorige</a>
            </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    } //end foreach
} else {
    $first = new WP_Query('post_type=success-stories&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="hide-large blogpost-link">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            <?php $thumbnail = get_field('sv_thumbnail_image'); ?>
            <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>)"></div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <?php
                            $client_image = get_field('blog_client_logo');
                            if( ! empty($client_image) ):
                                echo '<img src="' . $client_image['url'] . '" alt="">';
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vertical-centered text-center text">
                        <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                        <a class="btn inline-block solid-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lees verder</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="show-medium  small-6 prev previous-link">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&larr; Vorige</a>
        </div>

    <?php   wp_reset_query();
} ?>


<?php $nextPost = get_next_post(); ?>
<?php if( $nextPost) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'success-stories',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'include'               => $nextPost->ID
    );
    $nextPost = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($nextPost as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);  ?>

        <div class="hide-medium blogpost-link next">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            <?php $thumbnail = get_field('sv_thumbnail_image'); ?>
            <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>)"></div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <?php
                            $client_image = get_field('blog_client_logo');
                            if( ! empty($client_image) ):
                                echo '<img src="' . $client_image['url'] . '" alt="">';
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vertical-centered text-center text">
                        <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                        <a class="btn inline-block solid-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lees verder</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="show-medium  small-6 text-right next next-link">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Volgende &rarr; </a>
        </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
        } //end foreach
    } else {
        $last = new WP_Query('post_type=success-stories&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $last->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="hide-medium blogpost-link">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            <?php $thumbnail = get_field('sv_thumbnail_image'); ?>
            <div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>)"></div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <?php
                            $client_image = get_field('blog_client_logo');
                            if( ! empty($client_image) ):
                                echo '<img src="' . $client_image['url'] . '" alt="">';
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vertical-centered text-center text">
                        <h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                        <a class="btn inline-block solid-btn" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lees verder</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="show-medium small-6 text-right next next-link">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Volgende &rarr; </a>
            </div>
        </div> <?php 
    wp_reset_query();
}   ?>
```

**I found the Solution with some help of @kaddath**

There were two things wrong with my code.
First of all I made a mistake with the order. Inside my first loop I wrote the following

```
$first = new WP_Query('post_type=success-stories&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); $first->the_post();
```

In this situation, DESC should be ASC.

This brings me to the next problem, I forgot to setup the postdata at this point, I needed to add setup_postdata($first) and setup_postdata($last) to get details of the last and first post.

Comment: can it be a problem with your condition logic? as i read it, you are showing the 1st post when condition is false, but the condition is that it should have a previous post. If you want it to happen when you arrive at the last post, you should test if there is a next post instead of previous; the last post will always have a previous one, only the first one does not have any

Comment: oh i see now, in this test you always try to display the 1st post both either after the end or before beginning. You are probably only missing `setup_postdata($first);` and `setup_postdata($last);`, the data is not loaded in globals

Comment: To clear up what I want to achieve I added the other part of my code. If I don't get a response for the previous or next post I execute the code inside my else statement.

Comment: Fixed it! thank you so much for thinking with me.

Comment: no problem, what was the solution? it can help future readers..

Comment: True, I will post the solution in my post with credits to you ofcourse!